# Browser previous page button causes ribbon buttons unavailable

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, ribbon

We have got problem on sharepoint 2010 lists: user executes custom action redirecting user to some custom sharepoint page then user click previous page browser button and after selecting again item from the list item actions are not shown on the ribbon.